# How to use ngAnimate inside ngMessages?

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, ng-messages

I have an AngularJS form and I'd like to use animation on the error messages. Here is the current code I have right now:

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" required>

<div class="form-error-cont" ng-messages="form.name.$dirty && form.name.$error">
    <p ng-message="required" class="form-err">
        <i class="icon-remove"></i>
        <span class="text">Your name is required.</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

I have managed to use animation on `form-err` however I would like to animate the `<i>` element and the `<span>` element differently, when the `form-error` becomes 'active.'

Right now it's animating both of them at once.

Any idea how to animate them one by one?

Comment: can you show your code in fiddler or punker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class that capture the event on angular and make a specific animation. something similar to this.

```
.animate-repeat.ng-move,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter,
.animate-repeat.ng-leave {
   transition:all linear 0.5s;
   backface-visibility: hidden;

}
.animate-repeat.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.animate-repeat.ng-move,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter {
    opacity:0;
    max-height:0;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave,
.animate-repeat.ng-move.ng-move-active,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity:1;
    max-height:30px;
}
```

and your `html`

```
<div class="form-error-cont" ng-messages="form.name.$dirty && form.name.$error">
    <p ng-message="required" class="form-err animate-repeat">
        <i class="icon-remove"></i>
        <span class="text">Your name is required.</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

You can check the events and how to handle them here [ngAnimate](http://www.nganimate.org/)